# Can I write a plot on the screen to a file?

Tags: r, plot

In R, if I have already create a plot on the screen, is there a way to write it to a file, without rerun the plotting code again?

Is the quality same as plotting to a file directly? (e.g. when saved to pdf, can get copiable text and scalable showing of the plot)

Thanks!

Comment: In `ggplot` you can run `last_plot()`. Otherwise you can take a screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `savePlot` function for plots from the graphics package or `ggsave` for plots from ggplot2 package.

**Edit from comment**
`savePlot` only saves plots from cairo X11 devices (in my system it says that there is a similar function of the same name in windows).

As Ben Bolker suggested one can use `recordPlot` and `replayPlot`

I suppose one could do something like:

```
plot(1:10)
pl <- recordPlot()
png()
replayPlot(pl)
dev.off()
```

About the quality:
For `savePlot` you will probably get worse quality, see the Details in ?savePlot. Also savePlot does not save pdf files.

For `recordPlot`/`replayPlot` it will be exactly the same since the plot is re-created to be stored and you can change all the arguments of the `pdf`/`png`/`jpg` function you are using.

Comment: or possibly `recordPlot()`/`replayPlot()` ? `savePlot()` only claims to work on X11 devices (at least on my system)

Comment: Is the quality same as plotting to a file directly? (e.g. when saved to pdf, can get copiable text and scalable showing of the plot)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use `dev2bitmap`

```
plot(1:10)
dev2bitmap("test.png")
```

EDIT: Note that you need GhostScript installed. The above code ran fine on my machine (OSX 10.9.2) with 0 tinkering, and I'm pretty sure I never installed GS myself ... but it may have been installed with a larger package, etc, so YMMV.